# linux 22.04 sysstem unusable linux image 5.15.0-75/58 generic always give error 1 etc default res file does not exist and more

Tags: system, grub-efi

have tried updating ...impossible....
system space ended..only 1gb or even 800mb
no downloads accepted because

linux image 5.15.0-75/58 generic always give error 1 blocking everything

in the end the answer script was system possibly unusable.. try to inform of bug..

grub pc/grub-efi-arm64-    /shim signed------------all errors ---can reboot only from precedent versions...

sudo apt install gives other errors..

I would like to restart my ubuntu from scracth with maybe version 21.04 but cannot download for the problems mentioned above---

furthermore I cannot find the cd or dvd on sale in Italy where I live in abruzzo.

it seems like it is out of commerce.

Comment: There is not a single OS that will handle a too small / full system disk graciously. I'd guess you either was too shallow on the system or boot partition, or have not cleaned out e.g. old kernels (keep the one you use, and one spare). `$ dpkg --list | grep -E ^ii.*linux-image` lists one image on my machine, a choice I have made.